# Is Electric Potential real?

Tags: electrostatics, experimental-physics, potential, voltage

Is electric potential real? You might say it depends on what I mean by 'real' and I agree. But I remember reading about an experiment suggesting that electric potential is real, contra what had been previously thought. Are there any experiments that could have some bearing on the reality of electric potential?

Comment: First What you mean by 'real'? What that experiment meant when He says 'real'?

Comment: Do you mean local theories versus "spooky action at a distance"?

Comment: I was trying to recall the name of an experiment, which --- I now learned --- was 'Aharonov–Bohm effect'. I should not have used the word 'real', which is admittedly confusing, but I didn't know any way to describe the experiment without using it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably thinking of the [Aharonov–Bohm effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aharonov%E2%80%93Bohm_effect). Quoting from the article:

> The Aharonov–Bohm effect, sometimes called the Ehrenberg–Siday–Aharonov–Bohm effect, is a quantum mechanical phenomenon in which an electrically charged particle is affected by an electromagnetic potential (Φ, A), despite being confined to a region in which both the magnetic field B and electric field E are zero.

> It is generally argued that Aharonov–Bohm effect illustrates the physicality of electromagnetic potentials, Φ and A.

> The Aharonov–Bohm effect shows that the local E and B fields do not contain full information about the electromagnetic field, and the electromagnetic four-potential, (Φ, A), must be used instead. By Stokes' theorem, the magnitude of the Aharonov–Bohm effect can be
> calculated using the electromagnetic fields alone, or using the
> four-potential alone. But when using just the electromagnetic fields,
> the effect depends on the field values in a region from which the test
> particle is excluded. In contrast, when using just the electromagnetic
> four-potential, the effect only depends on the potential in the region
> where the test particle is allowed.

> In classical electromagnetism the two descriptions were equivalent. With the addition of quantum theory, though, the electromagnetic potentials Φ and A are seen as being more fundamental.

Answer (score 3):

Electric potential, like gravitational potential (height), can be measured. What might seem "less than real" about it's only measureable relative to something else - just like height. When we say "2000 m elevation", we mean 2000m elevation above the ground. When we say 120V, we mean 120V above some ground potential we define to be 0V.

If you consider "measurable" to be a sufficient criterion for "real", then it's real. Beyond that you're starting to get into philosophy.

Comment: I totally agree with you, basically. I was just looking for a well-known experiment of which name I could not recall, and the way I described the experiment seem to have caused some unnecessary distractions.

Answer (score 0):

For an electrostatic field, the force is conservative and therefore the work done by the field can be evaluated as the negative of the change in a potential energy.  Voltage is the potential energy per unit charge.  A negative difference in voltage between two points in a circuit means the E field does positive work in moving a charge from the initial to the final points. It is the same concept as for a conservative gravitational field.  For a uniform gravitational field g; -mg(h2 - h1) is the work done by gravity in moving from height h1 to height h2.  Electric potential is merely a convenient way of addressing the work done by a conservative electric field.